# How to use fiber-optic LC connector with my MacBook Pro for access to LTO-5 tape drive?

Tags: backup, archive

I'd like to use an LTO-5 tape drive to provide long term backup storage for files on my MacBook Pro that I wish to archive.  It appears the drive uses a fiber-optic LC connector.  Is there a way to connect such a drive to my MacBook Pro so I can back up files using it from my laptop?  If not, is there a LTO tape solution that works with MacBooks?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of connecting a MacBook (any modern laptop) to a fiber channel drive/drive subsystem is with a a device like the [ATTO Thunderlink FC3162](http://radnex.us/atto_tb3_fibre-channel-adapter), however, they are prohibitively expensive.

What might be a much cheaper and more effective alternative is to build another machine (a cheap PC will work well) and install a Fibre Channel HBA to connect to your LTO tape system.  I’ve done something very similar with FreeBSD and a Fibre Channel array that served as storage and Time Capsule backup using drives; I’m sure a tape solution would work just as easily.

Comment: Do any of the LTO tape drives not use fibre optic?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by the question.

Comment: Are there LTO drives that more readily can be used with a MacBook, e.g., don't have LC optical out.

Comment: Doing an Internet search, I found the [MagStore LT08](https://amzn.to/2PYa8Jd) which is Thunderbolt 3 to Tape - no Fibre channel conversion necessary.  It too is very expensive, however and I’ve never actually used this.